# Spring Cloud Stream - use spring cloud function("Function" specifically) to expose as rest endpoint and publish to a topic

Tags: spring, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

With Spring Cloud Stream - is it possible to use spring cloud function("function" specifically) to expose as rest endpoint and publish to a topic - something like below-

```
@Bean
  public Function<String,String> postLoginEvent() {
    return valFrmRest -> valFrmRest;
  }
```

Currently if I try this, the endpoint isn't exposed and I get 404. As a workaround, I used an `EmitterProcessor` to get input from rest endpoint and separately have a supplier return this processor to publish to a topic. Not sure if what I am asking is technically possible, but it might be a pretty common usecase and it will be nice to have out-of-the-box functionality available. Any thoughts? Thank you in advance for sharing your inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have it as a REST endpoint and then use `StreamBridge` API to publish it programmatically. See the details [here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/3.0.6.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_using_streambridge).

Here is a [sample](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/master/streambridge-samples/stream-bridge-avro) using `StreamBridge`.

Comment: Thank you @sobychacko! exactly what I was looking for. Thanm you this is helpful.